# how do I check if a circle shape is touched to apply actions to the shape e.g. change color of the shape or to update the score?

Tags: android, libgdx

So I am new to android games development and I have 4 CircleMapObjects which are yellow coloured I am using an InputProcessor to manage touch/click events. Now in the touchDown() method what I want is when a Circle is touched/clicked in the game (anywhere inside the circle ) then it should change to say the colour green. I am using the libgdx framework and am new to the framework, I have come across Actor however I've found that it draws rectangular shapes from looking at the API.

The InputHandler class:

```
public class InputHandler implements InputProcessor {

private Spot spot;


public InputHandler(Spot spot){

    this.spot = spot;
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    float distanceX = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((spot.getSpots()[0].getCircle().x - (screenX)), 2));
    float distanceY = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow((spot.getSpots()[0].getCircle().y - (screenY)), 2));

    //Below is for testing purposes not to do with touching a circle but touching a particular 
    //region on the screen
    //float distance = distanceX + distanceY;
//  System.out.println(distanceX);
//  System.out.println(distanceY);
//  System.out.println(spot.getSpots()[0].isVisible() + "" + "Color: " + spot.getSpots()[0].getColor());
    System.out.println("CLICKED: " + " x: " + screenX + " y: " + screenY);

            if (screenX > 45 && screenY < 431)
            {
                spot.getSpots()[0].setColor(Color.RED);
                System.out.println("This works!");
            }


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

The Spot class:

```
public class Spot {

private float x;
private float y;
private float radius;

//Use CircleMapObject instead?
private CircleMapObject spot_1, spot_2, spot_3, spot_4;
private CircleMapObject spotList[];

private float elapsedTime;
private int index;



public Spot(float x, float y, float radius){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;

    //each spot initialised
    spot_1 = new CircleMapObject(x,y,radius);
    spot_2 = new CircleMapObject(x, y-228,radius);
    spot_3 = new CircleMapObject(x+440,y,radius);
    spot_4 = new CircleMapObject(x+440,y-228,radius);

    //spot list initialised
    spotList = new CircleMapObject[4];

    //adding the spots to the spotlist
    spotList[0] = spot_1;
    spotList[1] = spot_2;
    spotList[2] = spot_3;
    spotList[3] = spot_4;

    elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    index = 0;


}

public void update(float delta){


}
```

}

The Gamescreen where the inputHandler is set:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {


private GameWorld world;
private GameRenderer render;

private Spot spot;


public GameScreen(){

    float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    System.out.println("Screen width: " + screenWidth + ", " + "Screen height: " + screenHeight);
    float gameWidth = 136;
    float gameHeight = screenHeight / (screenWidth / gameWidth);

    world = new GameWorld();
    render = new GameRenderer(world);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(world.getSpot()));

}
```

... (there's more code in the GameScreen class but this is the only reference of the InputHandler used in this class. This also applies to the rest of the code.)

Comment: Unproject touch position using camera. Then check diameter of circle and position and detect if circle is touched. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify this you only need to check if the distance of the circle vs touch location is less then the radius of the circle to detect a hit. Simple vector math does the trick, we calculate the distance horizontally and vertically and with Pythagoras (A² + B² = C²) we can calculate the final distance.

```
distance = √(circleX - (touchX))² + ((circleY) - touchY)²

if (Math.abs(distance) < circleRadius)
{
    //Touch within circle...
}
```

Libgdx has some [vector functions](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html) for calculating the distance.

```
if (touchVector.dst(circleOrigin) < circleRadius)
{
    //Touch within circle...
}
```

When i am talking about touchVector you need to use Vector2 and put your coordinates in. When working with positions, directions, velocities, etc you should be using the Vector2 class or Vector3 for 3D environments.

```
Vector2 touchVector = new Vector2(x,y);
float distance = touchVector.dst(new Vector2(circleOriginX, circleOriginY));
```

Comment: Math.abs doesn't take boolean conditions this doesn't work :S.

Comment: Oh another thing, I randomly tested if anything happens with the circle when say I click on a particular part of the screen just to check if the touchDown method was working after registering the inputProcessor in the game screen class and I did print statement after say setting the circle invisible and the isvisible from the system print received false as it should however this change wasn't applied on the screen the circle still remained visible.

Comment: I forgot a parenthesis, not tested anything. Did you try the gdx vector method dst? It returns distance. The first part is just to show you the math behind it.

Comment: 2nd comment is too vague,  different question?  Need code and a clear explanation.

Comment: I have posted snippets of my code which will hopefully make things a bit more clearer. What I was saying is when I clicked anywhere in the region as shown here `if (screenX > 45 && screenY < 431)` the if statement executed which did lead to this being printed to the console `System.out.println("This works!");` however the shape didn't turn red. Now in my render method which is located in a different class not shown above, inside the render method, all I have done is rendered the 4 CircleMapObjects to yellow using a for loop on the CircleMapList array where these shapes are contained.

Comment: Oh I tried doing the .dst() method and it's not working it didn't even ask for any imports not sure if there's some jar file I need to add to my libraries to use it :/

Comment: No, it is a method of LibGDX Vector2. Check my answer for a link to the class.

Comment: Ah I'm a fool >.<. Right I've done that and it seems like the if statement will always pass false. I have used an orthographic camera so I'm uncertain if that has anything to do with the x, y coordinate change :/. I did a system print to the console for the distance and it gives me 213 when I'm clicking right on the circle. Just to be sure the circleOriginX and y are the circle's x and y coordinates? that's what I passed into the .dst() method which are stored in circleOriginX and circleOriginY.

Comment: it makes sense what the code is doing, but for some reason I won't get a difference within the radius of the circle it's far off from that value

Comment: Okay so when I click say slightly below the circle it executes the if statement and that's about 120-150 places down the y axis so not too far away from where the circle is positioned which is at 248 on the y axis but still not on the circle.

Comment: Try placing some temporary rectangles on where you clicked can help you fine tune. But are you sure you are doing things right with the orthographic camera? The camera can defer from world position and both of those defer from screen position. Also drawing and the cam has a upward Y axis and the input parameters have a downward Y axis, this especially is super annoying.

Comment: Well as a temporary fix I used addition for the x,y, radius of each circle by a fixed number and that solved the issue, whenever I touch within the circle right when the outline begins it turns green while ensuring this doesn't go outside the circle. Though I understand this isn't effective in the long run because when and if I decide to change the radius of my circle, that Math will become completely redundant so I would have to recalculate.

Comment: Possibly the orthographic camera is the reason behind the inconsistency between the touch coordinates and positioning of the circles which I will have to take a look at later down the line regarding that.